# Converting LiDAR ellipsoidal heights to orthometric heights?

Tags: coordinate-system, interpolation, lidar, ellipsoid, geoid

Is there any tool to convert all Z attributes (ellipsoid h) value into orthometric height (H)? The idea is, having a point cloud (.las) and geoid undulation EGM08 (.asc) get a point cloud (.las) with Z orthometric values.

To get orthometric heights is necessary calculate N (geoid height) and is required using a bi-linear interpolation.

[image]

How can this interpolation be done?

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html

Comment: Terrascan can do it, though I'm not sure how to push all the buttons to do that. Where did you get the LAS from? Can you ask your supplier to give the LAS files to you in orthometric height? Isn't it EGM08 (Earth Gravitational Model) not EMG08? It may seem like being pedantic but it could make a big difference in searching for the right term.

Comment: There's lots of ways to attack this problem. Assuming you want to stay in Python, if you have your own grid files, you could read up the points with LASpy, read the grid file using GDAL, and write out a new file with LASpy representing your orthometric heights. If you want to simply run a command, PDAL can convert ellipsoid (EPSG:4326) LAS data to orthometric (EPSG:5773) using the vertical datum transformation capabilities of Proj.4. The question needs more detail on what you have and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Have you looked into VDatum from NOAA? https://vdatum.noaa.gov/

Comment: I have a .las from LiDAR with more than 4M points. I check the height of these points comparing with a surface model, and I find out that Z values are elipsoid height.
I need to transform Z values into a orthometric. @MichaelStimson you are in the path, I made a python script that reads a .asc (EGM08) and construct a function ((scipy.interpolate.interp2d) to get a geoid height giving latitude and longitud. I checked the results with a few points and it's ok. 
To avoid make a module for this task, I asked for a tool that can make this. But I think I am very close to the solution with LASpy.

Comment: Fair enough. Although Terrascan *can* do it I wrote my own C++ console program to do what you're doing in python; 4 million points (or was that pulses?) is a *very* small number of records when it comes to LAS, so you should be able to process that in python but if this is something you're doing regularly or for larger areas you should consider some LiDAR processing software like Terrascan, mostly for fixing when you find anomalies in the LiDAR that affects your output.

Comment: @HowardButler The GRID cells are very large, consequently the difference in values between one cell and the adjacent is significant, if you simply read the value in the GRID you will end up with 'steps' in the LiDAR... you **must** interpolate! Your 2nd method however sounds interesting provided you get the right vertical datums, but still I'm a bit doubtful that the correct gravitational model will be used, several can exist (there's at least 3 I've seen for East Coast Australia, 2 for New Zealand, as well as about a dozen MSL vertical datums), so which model does PDAL use?

Comment: PDAL uses whichever model is defined in vertcs.csv of Proj4 for the given EPSG code. Proj.4 does interpolate, and it's not just stepped.

Comment: Only to do that? Is Terrascan free license just for do that?.
Yes, I have to do this like a batch, but this is not a problem. isn't it?

Comment: @MichaelStimson, I've used a model generated by an governmental institute and is very accurate (it is based on EGM08), and test data is from a geodesic stations and the error is lower than centimeter.

Comment: Terrascan is not free (that I know of), it runs in Microstation (which isn't free either). If you have Esri and 3d analyst (or LP360) already you can do some minor editing in LAS dataset but it's *very slow*, LASTools has an editor... I don't want to promote one software over the others. It's possible that you already have the tools you need. The model endorsed by your governments' geodetic agency is likely to be the best for your situation - just beware if you're trying to match to another dataset from another country, the differences can be significant.

Answer (score 4):

[PDAL](https://pdal.io) can do this with its [filters.reprojection](https://www.pdal.io/stages/filters.reprojection.html) capability, which is based on the [vertical datum](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/wiki/VerticalDatums) transformation capabilities of [Proj.4](http://proj4.org).

```
pdal translate input.las output.las reprojection 
    --filters.reprojection.in_srs="EPSG:4326+4326" 
    --filters.reprojection.out_srs="EPSG:4326+3855"
```

Make sure that [egm08_25.gtx](http://download.osgeo.org/pub/proj/vdatum/egm08_25/egm08_25.gtx), defined in `GDAL_DATA`'s `vertcs.csv` file as `EPSG:3855` is available in `/usr/local/share/gdal` or wherever your system's `GDAL_DATA` is defined.

PDAL is installable via OSGeo4W or Docker. See https://www.pdal.io/download.html for details.

Comment: Thanks first of all.
What is *.gtx? I´ve never seen this before. I use a .asc [.asc](ftp://ftp.geodesia.ign.es/geoide/arcGIS/), may be is usefull for this problem because y use it and the resoults are perfect. In this resource I can´t see this *.gtx format.
In this pdal function, the egm grid is to interpolate is fixed in vertex?
Where can you define the interpolation method?

Comment: GTX is the raster format that Proj.4 uses for grid shift files.

Comment: FWIW, I have packaged PDAL 1.6.0 including vertical datums here: https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/neteler/pdal/   (I hope I got it right :-)